# Can two client browsers use the same port to talk to a web server?

Tags: tcp

When a socket is created between a client and host, it includes the IP address, protocol used and port number of both.

Suppose I have socket A (10.0.0.1, TCP, 50000) and (10.0.0.2, TCP, 50000) each connecting to (11.11.11.11, TCP, 80) (a web server).

Will there be a conflict at the web server since both sockets are using the same port?

Comment: Two TCP connections differ if one of the 4-tuple (source IP and port, destination IP and port) differs. So the scenario you describe is not a problem. If this would have been a problem it would be a nightmare since then all systems on the network/internet would somehow need to synchronize with each other in order to not use the same source port when accessing the same server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The connection is identified by a 5-tuple that includes the source IP

Therefore, the server sees 2 different, distinguishable connections.

Answer (score -2):

While Steffen Ulrich's answer is valid, it's not quite what happens.

Your web server at `11.11.11.11:80` is only listening for one connection. When `10.0.0.1:50000` connects to it, it immediately assigns a new port for it, say 49001, and tells 10.0.0.1 that it is now talking to `11.11.11.11:49001` and goes back to listening for connections on port 80.

Now when `10.0.0.2:50000` connects, it is immediately told that it's now talking to `11.11.11.11:49007`, and the web server goes back watching for people who want to connect to port 80.

So ports are different, and there is no conflict.

Comment: This isn't true for anything TCP-based. (Or even most things UDP-based, except perhaps TFTP.) It *was* how connection establishment in ARPANET NCP worked, but they moved away from that mechanism some 50 years ago.

Comment: Funny, I'm still being told to code servers that way. The Linux Programming API explicitly says that when a new thread is launched for a connection that has been made, it's assigned a new port... well, documentation, even recently released documentation, may still be behind the times I guess.

Comment: Can you cite sources for that? (I can cite Wireshark captures showing that this doesn't happen...)

Comment: Alas, no. Seems I misremembered something I saw in _The Linux Programming Interface_ (Kerrisk 2010), probably conflated it with ancient historical documents from somewhere else. Ah, well...

Comment: It honestly sounds like something that would refer to Mach IPC ports (perhaps on Hurd or macOS) rather than TCP ports... As far as I know, Linux doesn't even provide anything that would automatically launch new threads for new connections (there are thread pool libraries but even they don't have such influence on the TCP handshake), on the other hand that definitely sounds like something that would be found on Mach platform.

Comment: _TLPI_ chapter 60 does explicitly talk about launching per-connection threads for the connections in the sample echo server.

Comment: Are you sure it didn't say a new server thread (for a new connection) gets a new _PID=process-id_? That is a property of Linux that differs from other Unixes and can matter to programming.